# How to name organizations, companies, etc. in APA?

Tags: citations

when naming an organization in APA, such as Apple, does the company website also have to be added somewhere (in parantheses or as a footnote)?

For example:
(1) In 2022, the largest manufacturer of smartphones is Apple.

(2) ... is Apple*     Footnote: * [www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com)

(3) ... is Apple ([www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if an organization is widely known (Apple, Google, etc.), one can omit explicit references to its webpage. Otherwise, the 7th edition of APA style [recommends](https://columbiacollege-ca.libguides.com/apa/websites) the following template

> Corporation/Group/Organization's Name. (Year webpage was last
> updated/published, Month Day if given). Title of page: Subtitle (if
> any).
> URL

to cite a

> Page or Section from a Website Created by a Corporate or Group
> Author''.

The link above includes an example, as well:

> **Example**
> Canadian Cancer Society. (2013, April 14). Cancer research.
> http://www.cancer.ca/en/cancer-information/cancer-101/cancer-research/?region=on
>
> **In-Text Paraphrase**
> (Corporation/Group's Name, Year)
>
> Example: (Canadian Cancer Society, 2013)
>
> **In-Text Quote**  (Corporation/Group's Name, year, Section Name section,
> para. Paragraph Number if more than one paragraph in section)
>
> Example: (Canadian Cancer Society, 2013, Behavioural research section,
> para. 2)
>
> Note: When there are no visible page numbers or paragraph numbers, you
> may cite the section heading and the paragraph number to identify
> where your quote came from.